# What do the differences in the Pearson & Spearman correlation tell us about the variables?

Tags: spss, pearson-r, spearman-rho

I have conducted correlations for the variables gross weekly pay and total hours worked. The Pearson's coefficient between two variables is (r=.51). Whereas for the Spearman's correlation, the coefficient value is (rho=.68).

What do the differences between the two correlations tell us about the two variables? How would one go about interpreting this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing whatsoever.  Perhaps a little bit could be said if we also knew the sample size.  Surely you have much more information than just these two statistics!  What is the problem you are *really* trying to address?

Comment: Usually a much higher rs than r would suggest non-linearity. However, given that both the sr and r values in this case are not very high, there is something else going on, some predictive variable(s) that is(are) missing.

Comment: I would suggest a scatterplot to see better what the relationship might be.